# 2 LG 29 screen, one 2560x1080 one 1920x1080

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

Just bought 2 LG 29 monitors but when I plugged everything in, only one(HDMI plug) can get to the 2560x1080 resolution.  The other monitor(DVI plug) can only get to 1920x1080. Now I read on here on another post that DVI can't do 2560x1080 and 60hz, I dont know how to change to lower and see if that will be a quick fix.

My video card only has one HDMI port, one displayport, one DVI, one VGA

Is there a simple fix?  I dont know whats the limiting factor here.

**Relevant Hardware:**

- Motherboard: ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING
- CPU: Intel i7-6700K
- Monitor(s): LG 29UB55-B Black 29"

Comment: Get a DisplayPort to HDMI adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

If the monitors have DisplayPort, you should use that instead. It can easily handle [2650 x ____ resolutions at 60Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Resolution_and_refresh_frequency_limits_for_DisplayPort).

If you can't use DisplayPort, then you will need to check if your graphics card and monitor support [Dual Link DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Specifications), which will support up to 2560 × 1600 at 60 Hz.

Comment: thank you! ordered a display to hdmi cable and hopefully that fixed any issues  :)

Comment: @technewbie No problem. Remember to mark answers that answer your question as accepted. :)

Comment: just got my display to hdmi...  still can't see 2650x ___ on my settings...  any other suggestions?

Comment: @technewbie Can you edit your question to include graphics card and monitor makes/models?

Comment: I use the onboard graphics card from (1) ASUS Z170 PRO GAMING LGA 1151 Intel Z170 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 ATX Intel Motherboard (2) and use LG 29UB55-B Black 29" 5ms (GTG) IPS 21:9 UltraWide IPS LED Backlight LCD Monitor, 2560 x 1080

Comment: @technewbie If it's onboard graphics, your CPU is in charge of the graphics, what model CPU do you have?

Comment: I have the  i7-6700K

Comment: @technewbie: Align them vertically instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i tried portrait view but still get the same settings

Comment: Not portrait view, one above the other.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams tried that just now, still can't get 2650x to show up on display settings